# Python Matplotlib: General Purpose Graphing with Twinx()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am attempting to develop a fairly general purpose graph using matplotlib but keep getting an error `ValueError: left cannot be >= right`. My code is:

```
def perf_plot(x, y, data, title = ''):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import statsmodels.api as sm
    plt.style.use('ggplot')

    df = data

    if y == 'slope':
        z = 'bp01'
    else: 
        z = 'slope'

    y = df[y].astype(float)
    x = df[x].astype(float)
    z = df[z].astype(float)

    blue = '#348EA9'
    orange = '#F48B37'
    green = '#52BA9B'
    red = '#EF4846'

    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    fig.suptitle(title, fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
    fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)
    ax1.scatter(x ,y, color = orange)

    lowess_y = sm.nonparametric.lowess(y, x ,frac=0.1)
    ax1.plot(lowess_y[:, 0], lowess_y[:, 1], color = blue)
    ax1.set_ylabel(y, color = blue)
    ax1.set_xlabel(x, color = 'b')

    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    lowess_z = sm.nonparametric.lowess(z, x, frac=0.1)
    ax2.plot(lowess_z[:, 0], lowess_z[:, 1], color = green)
    ax2.set_ylabel(z, color = green)

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    return
```

After some googling, I found that this error is generally correlated with tight_layout() and the use of a title. Removing the title does not resolve the problem, but if I remove tight_layout the graph does print but both axis are placed on the left side of the graph. As the point is to do something like [this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html), I am not really how to get the duel axis without tight_layout. Ideas?

Error code:

```
perf_plot(x_, y_, df1)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-149-36ff57804093>", line 1, in <module>
    perf_plot(x_, y_, df1)

  File "<ipython-input-148-ef2f325b64f9>", line 37, in perf_plot
    fig.tight_layout()

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1755, in tight_layout
    self.subplots_adjust(**kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1620, in subplots_adjust
    self.subplotpars.update(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 228, in update
    raise ValueError('left cannot be >= right')

ValueError: left cannot be >= right
```

Comment: What about a [mcve] of the issue? At the moment nobody can run the code. Also, state the versions of libraries in use.

Comment: libraries are up to date. How could no one run the code? Its quite complete.

Comment: You will find out that if you copy the code and try to run it it will not work because the function is not called anywhere and it is completely unclear what data should be put in.

Answer (score 0):

The error was being caused by

```
y = df[y].astype(float)
x = df[x].astype(float)
z = df[z].astype(float)
```

where

```
ax1.set_ylabel(y, color = blue)
ax1.set_xlabel(x, color = 'b')
```

causing the labels to be dataframes. This was problem solved by significantly increasing the figure size via:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8)
```